# Historical GIS data

Tags: data, administrative-boundaries

I am looking for geographical boundaries of the Pale of Settlement - a region of Imperial Russia in which permanent residency by Jews was allowed in the 19th century 
Will manage with most formats

Comment: http://worldmap.harvard.edu/maps/russianempire covers Imperiia you can export the layers out (KML)

Comment: @Mapperz thanks, i cannot see the pale of settlements mentioned among the layers

Comment: shouldn't this question and answer live on Open Data.se

Comment: @iant thank you i was not aware of the open data se

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to locate the Pale of Settlement you need to do a search

on http://worldmap.harvard.edu/maps/russianempire

[image]

Go to Add Layers

Search 'Pale'

Locate the Pale of Settlement

view on the map..